# How to load router default gateway in web URL's automatically on android studio

Tags: java, android, browser, autoload

what i am trying to do is when i open the browser i created it should automatically redirect the page to router default gateway, when connected on wifi.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Address = "http://" + ed1.getText().toString();
            WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
            webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


            web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            web1.loadUrl(Address);

        }
    });
}
```

the code above only allowed me the type manually. how to auto detect the default gateway and load router page when the activity start.

Comment: It looks to me that this has little to do with a WebView. Instead your problem is only 'how to determine the wifi gateway?'. Once you have the gateway ip i suppose you know how to use loadUrl to start the routers web interface. Please clear up.

Comment: yes to determine the wifi gateway ip and loadUrl to start the routers web interface. programmatic

Comment: Funny answer. It did not clear up anything.

Comment: yes i know how to load router page using gateway IP  , its that possible in WebView?  can your guide me how to auto convert router default gateway as a Link  etc: https://192.168.1.1  in textView or as web startup  , able to redirect to the router page without typing the ip manually . sorry for bad english

Comment: `how to auto convert router default gateway as a Link`. If you already determined the ip then what is the problem you have to make an url of it? Please try to explain the actual problem you have.

Comment: the code i am looking for is : how to get the router default gateway and convert to link , so end-user no need to worry about the DGateway ip

Comment: So two problems. Google for WifiManager code. Or 'android how to determine default gateway'.

Comment: Chiff I already try Google it can't find how to set default gateway as link to web browser